# java detect open ZipOutputStream or inflater which wasn't closed , there used to be open source class loader util

Tags: java, zip

i have big java application which is working allot with zip files
i want to detect where are the zip files whice are opend but didnt closed
using ZipOutputStream
or inflater
for example :

```
try {

    inflater = new Inflater();
    inflater.setInput(data);

    outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!inflater.finished()) {
        int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    output = outputStream.toByteArray();        
    //MISSING
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Fail to decompress given array bytes.");
    return data;
}
finally {
    if (outputStream != null) {
        //MISSING
    }
    //MISSING
}
```

i want to detect who in the code didnt closed or end the inflater.
i used to have open source helper java utility which i don't remember the name that used to
print the unclosed streams

can't remmber what is this utility name

Someone remembers?

Comment: I don’t understand.  It’s your code that didn’t call [end()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/Inflater.html#end%28%29).  Why do you need to detect who failed to do it?

Comment: its not my code , its legacy code (big one) that has memory leaks